# Using case_when in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, switch-statement, tidyverse

I am trying to use case_when as follows:

```
x <- 22
y <- runif(1)
z <- case_when (
    x <= 22 ~ "FT", 
    x >  22 & x <= 25 & y  < 0.5  ~ "FT",
    x >  22 & x <= 25 & y >= 0.5  ~ "PT",
    x >  25 & y >  0.9            ~ "PT",
    X >  25 & y <= 0.9            ~ "FT",
    TRUE ~ "PT")
```

When I run this I get

> Error in eval_bare(f[[2]], env) : object 'X' not found

Yet `x` is present

```
x
#[1] 22
```

Comment: You've got a typo in the second last `case_when` line: it should be lower-case `x` instead of `X` (you should've picked that up from the error message).

Answer (score 1):

As Maurits has mentioned there is a typo in your `case_when` statement. Change the uppercase last 'X' to 'x'

```
z <- case_when (
  x <= 22 ~ "FT", 
  x >  22 & x <= 25 & y  < 0.5  ~ "FT",
  x >  22 & x <= 25 & y >= 0.5  ~ "PT",
  x >  25 & y >  0.9            ~ "PT",
  x >  25 & y <= 0.9            ~ "FT",
  TRUE ~ "PT")

z
[1] "FT"
```